# displayhtml text on my page

Tags: android, html

Hi I am using these codes to show my `html` codes on my pages. I convert my doc to `html` by using https://wordhtml.com/ this web.
but no color changes and others on my apps. page? what can ı do?

```
 cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String htmlAsString = getString(R.string.html);
            Spanned htmlAsSpanned = Html.fromHtml(htmlAsString);
            vh = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vh);
            vh.setText(htmlAsSpanned);
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.baslik)).setVisibility(View.GONE); ((Button)findViewById(R.id.cb)).setVisibility(View.GONE); ((Button)findViewById(R.id.geri)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); ((Button)findViewById(R.id.db)).setVisibility(View.GONE); ((Button)findViewById(R.id.bb)).setVisibility(View.GONE); ((Button)findViewById(R.id.ck)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

[MY html codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyYXK.png)

my string files:

```
<string name="html">
  <![CDATA[
<p><strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">RED BOLD&nbsp;</span></strong></p> <p><span style="background-color:
#00ff00;">FONT</span></p> <h1>HEADER</h1>
  ]]>
```

but here is result. there is not red color . what is problem? why red color doesn't see?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is because you might have used a css and also some of the tags didnt work in android

Comment: You can use a `WebView`! There is a limitation in tags if you use that Html.fromHtml Spanned!

Comment: Use Android `WebView`!

Comment: ı used webview before but my application work too slow. for this reason I try these method. is there any solution?

Comment: @a.dem check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setText(Html.fromHtml(bodyData))` is **deprecated** after api **24**. Try this :

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p><strong><span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">RED BOLD&nbsp;</span></strong></p> <p><span style=\"background-color:
    #00ff00;\">FONT</span></p> <h1>HEADER</h1>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
 } else {
      myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p><strong><span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">RED BOLD&nbsp;</span></strong></p> <p><span style=\"background-color:
    #00ff00;\">FONT</span></p> <h1>HEADER</h1>"));
 }
```

Comment: Please escape your strings properly.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is using `WebView` You can achieve that,

In XMl page

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/q"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

then Activity class you can add this lines

```
q=findViewById(R.id.q);
    String s="<string name=\"html\">\n" +
            "  <![CDATA[\n" +
            "<p><strong><span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">RED BOLD&nbsp;</span></strong></p> <p><span style=\"background-color:\n" +
            "#00ff00;\">FONT</span></p> <h1>HEADER</h1>]]>";
    q.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, s, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```